How to pass variable from enviroment attribute to volume or another docker-compose places without .env file?
I want to pass default environment variable to use it if in -e variable wasn't passed anything. So, I do something like this
services:
  db:
    environment:
      - DATABASES_FOLDER=/raw_databases

    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - "${DATABASES_FOLDER}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

But when I do it, container sees just /postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
$DATABASES_FOLDER and just without "" is not working

move DATABASES_FOLDER=/raw_databases in a separate .env file, in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml.

Does this answer your question? How can I use environment variables in docker-compose?

Yes, I know this, I don't want to use .env file

Then the next best solution is probably a bash-script tat does some envsubst shenanigans. But to be honest, I do not understand why you wouldn't use the solution provided by docker-compose.

envsubst and another external templates are exessive. I don't want to use separate .env file for a few and maybe even just one variable.

Then hard-code the path. If this is also not an option, then the problem is to the best of my knowledge not solvable.

Compose has two different levels of environment variable handling.  When you say
volumes:
  - "${DATABASES_FOLDER}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

it looks at the host's environment and the .env file.  This is separate from when you say
environment:
  - DATABASES_FOLDER=/raw_databases

which sets an environment variable inside the container, but doesn't affect variable substitutions elsewhere in the file.
If you just want to use a default value, Compose supports Bourne-shell-style ${VARIABLE:-default} substitutions.  So possibly the path you're looking for is
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - "${DATABASES_FOLDER:-/raw_databases}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    # no environment: {DATABASES_FOLDER: ...} setting

If you run
DATABASES_FOLDER=$HOME/myapp docker-compose up -d

then it will store the data in $HOME/myapp/postgres.  The DATABASES_FOLDER environment variable won't be visible inside the container at all.

Yes, I know the solution like ${DATABASES_FOLDER:-/raw_databases}. It partly resolves my problem, but I don't like it because I should use this DATABASES_FOLDER in a few places and it will be a lot of duplicated code. Would be nice to create DATABASES_FOLDER just in one place that I will able to ancor in yaml.
